# Assign Rank to each row based on the type of row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table

DiagnosisCodes

```
Sequence  Type        Value
 1         Diagnosis   123
 22        Diagnosis   456
 38        Principal   111
 4         Diagnosis   789
 53        Principal   222
```

I need to select from the Diagnosis table and assign a rank to each row based on the Sequence and Type. Lowest Sequence gets the lowest rank for that Type.For example: Sequence 1 is the lowest sequence for Type "Diagnosis" so its rank should be 1 similarly Sequence 4 is second lowest for type "Diagnosis" so its rank should be 2. Sequence 38 is lowest for Type "Principal" so should be ranked 1 and so on.

Output I expect:

```
Sequence  Type        Value Rank
 1         Diagnosis   123  1
 22        Diagnosis   456  3
 38        Principal   111  1
 4         Diagnosis   789  2
 53        Principal   222  2
```

I was thinking of using pivot or partition but not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Row_Number` Window Function to create the rank

```
select sequence , Type, Value,
       row_number() over(partition by Type order by sequence) As [Rank] 
From yourtable
```

**Note :** In case of `tie` if you need same `rank` then use `Dense_Rank` instead of `Row_number`